# Topology induced by the norm $||x||_T \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=} ||T(x)||$ is the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

I have been working on a few exercises that were given to us as practice for a topology class that I am currently taking. I managed to solve all exercises after a few days of thinking, however, there is one exercise that I have not been able to figure out at all:

> Let $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ be an injective
> linear transformation. Define a norm $|| \cdot ||_T$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$
> in the following manner:
>
> $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n , \, ||x||_T \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=} ||T(x)||$$
>
> where $||\cdot||$ is the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that
> $||\cdot||_T$ is a norm and that the topology induced by $||\cdot||_T$ is the usual topology
> on $\mathbb{R}^n$

I have been able to show that $||\cdot||_T$ is a norm without any issue, however I have not been able to figure out how to even start proving the second part. I have tried showing that both topologies are finer than the other with the intent of reaching the conclusion that they are equivalent by showing that all open sets of one are open sets of the other directly and also by using the equivalent basis definition, however I have not been able to find any success.

I feel that I am completely stumped, and any suggestions on how to begin would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Side-Remark: This follows from the fact that all norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent, see for example https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.335/norm-equivalence.pdf

Comment: What is your definition of "usual" topology in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Commonly encountered are the product topology and the metric topology induced by the Euclidean metric. These two are of course equivalent, but you should probably specify as you will use it in your proof.

Comment: @K.Jiang This question came right after a section on norms and metrics so I have been using the metric topology. There is however also an exercise to prove that the two topologies mentioned by you are equivalent, so any of them can be used without issue.

Comment: Well, $T$ takes open balls to open ellipsoids (with axes scaled by the eigenvalues of $T$) and $T^{-1}$ takes open balls to open ellipsoids (with axes scaled by the reciprocal eigenvalues)...  Open ellipsoids contain open balls and are contained in open balls...

Comment: @EricTowers This is true only when $k=0$.

Comment: @PaulFrost : A open 3-ellipsoid in $\Bbb{R}^{15}$ is still an open ellipsoid.

Comment: @EricTowers An "open 3-ellipsoid" in $\mathbb{R}^{15}$ does not contain open balls (of $\mathbb{R}^{15}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be concrete let's say we want to prove that the topology induced by $||\cdot||_T$ is the same as the topology induced by one of the standard norms $||\cdot||$. We will apply a series of reductions. Since each topology has as basis the set of open balls, it suffices to show that the open balls of $||\cdot||$ are open in $|| \cdot ||_T$ and vice-versa. Since translation by $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism under any norm topology, it suffices to do this for open balls centered at $0$.

If you're slightly more clever/careful with the last step, it actually suffices to check that every $||\cdot||$ ball around $0$ contains some $||\cdot||_T$ ball around $0$ and vice versa. In fact in the given situation it will be possible to pick the radii of these balls to depend linearly on each other by showing that there exist constants $c$ and $C > 0$ such that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$c ||x|| \le ||x||_T \le C||x|| .$$
One can show this generally for any two norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I leave it to you to find such $c$ and $C$ in terms of the matrix of $T$: the exact values will depend on which of the standard norms you choose as $||\cdot||$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sphere $S=\{x\in\mathbb R^n \colon\lVert x\rVert = 1\}$ and set
$$
c = \min \lVert T(S) \rVert,\qquad C=\max \lVert T(S) \rVert.
$$
Then
$$
c \lVert x \rVert \leq \lVert x\rVert_T
 \leq C \lVert x\rVert \quad\forall x\in\mathbb R^n$$
which implies that the identity $id\colon (\mathbb R^n,\lVert \bullet\rVert) \to (\mathbb R^n,\lVert \bullet\rVert_T)$ and its inverse $id^{-1}$ are continuos in the metric sense, and thus also in the topological sense. But that implies that the two topologies are equal.

Note that the minimum and maximum above exists since $S$ is compact and therefore $T(S)$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard to prove that all norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent (see Alex's answer), but I do not think that proving this general theorem was the intention of the exercise.

We can use the following well-known

**Lemma.** Each linear map $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is continuous with respect to the standard Euclidean topologies.

Now consider $T$ as in your question. Let $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$. The $T(e_i)$ are linearly independent, hence $\mathbb R^{n+k}$ has a basis of the form $b_1 = T(e_1), \ldots, b_n = T(e_n), b_{n+1},\ldots, b_{n+k}$. There exists a unique linear map $f : \mathbb R^{n+k} \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $f(b_i) = e_i$ for $i \le n$ and $f(b_i) = 0$ for $i > n$. It is continuous with respect to the standard Euclidean topologies.

Let $\mathbb R^n_T$ denote $\mathbb R^n$ with the topology induced by $\lVert - \rVert_T$. By definition of $\lVert - \rVert_T$ we see that

1. $T : \mathbb R^n_T \to \mathbb R^{n+k}$ is continuous.
2. $T^{-1} : T(\mathbb R^n) \to \mathbb R^n_T$ is continuous, where $T(\mathbb R^n)$ carries the subspace topology induced from $\mathbb R^{n+k}$.

Hence $f \circ T : \mathbb R^n_T \to  \mathbb R^n$ is continuous. But $f \circ T$ is nothing else than the identity map.

Similarly $id : \mathbb R^n \to  \mathbb R^n_T$ is continuous. In fact, it is nothing else than
$$\mathbb R^n \xrightarrow{T}  T(\mathbb R^n)  \xrightarrow{T^{-1}} \mathbb R^n_T .$$
Note that $\mathbb R^n \xrightarrow{T}  T(\mathbb R^n)$ is continuous because $T : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^{n+k}$ is continuous and $T(\mathbb R^n)$ has subspace topology induced from $\mathbb R^{n+k}$.

We conclude that  $id : \mathbb R^n \to  \mathbb R^n_T$ is a homeomorphism.